# In Javascript, is it possible to pass commands in the site's console log like you would in a Terminal?

Tags: javascript

For example, when someone goes to my site's console log, I want them to be able to enter a few commands ("help", "about", etc). The command enter will then return some text.

I know you can use dialogue boxes, but I am looking more for a Terminal type experience.

This is purely meant to be a bit of an easter egg, just to enhance the user experience for the nosey types!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, why not. Define some global variables:

```
window.help = 'Easter egg';
```

Comment: Shot, thanks mate! It seems to only accept a string though, so I can't for example make a function that contains a lot of text lines, and just pass that to window.help. 

It's cool though, will figure out a way to make it work!

Comment: Just for completion: You can also assign a self invoking function as a global variable, which returns text based on some data like the time (different greetings for example) or the user's geo location

Comment: @TraaidMark - yes it is possible to use functions, as a said before, you can use a self invoking function like this: `window.help = (function(){/*code*/})();` and then if the user puts `help` into the console, the function get's executed

Comment: @Markai This function gets executed immediately when the code is interpreted by a browser. But yeah, it will display the last value in the function body.

Comment: @VisioN if you assign it to a variable it should not get executed immediately. I just tested it out with the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and IE and it does not get executed immediately

Comment: @Markai `window.help = (function(){/*code*/})();` will be executed immediately, as you have `()` at the end.

Comment: @Markai I know it `:)` The code gets executed inline and what you have stored in `help` variable is what the code returns back. Try this in the console: `window.help = (function() { console.log('test'); return 'Easter egg' })();` and you'll see.

Comment: @Markai - Can confirm this works well! Thanks man. Will try to get creative with this now!

Comment: @VisioN okay now I get what you mean, I thought, you meant, that the function get's instantly displayed in the console.